# How can I use *ngFor iterator variable inside interpolation in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular property that has subproperties following an interface created by myself. I would like to use it  in order to avoid writing each line title and then matching the data I get from my Data Base.

For this, I would like to use *ngFOR and interpolation. I have tried several things, but I can't find the syntax or the right alternative to achieve this.

My question is, how can I use the *ngFor iterator variable inside the interpolation of my variable ?

Here is an exemple of what i would like to achieve :

Property exemple in TS side :

```
//Custom property
information: customInterface[] = [
    {
      zone: "europe",
      names: [
        { dbName: "city1", title: "Paris" },
        { dbName: "city2", title: "Madrid" },
        { dbName: "city3", title: "Berlin" },
        { dbName: "city4", title: "Rome" },
      ]
    },
    { zone: "XX",
      names:[
XX]}
  ];

//Property 2 sotring data I actually want to show from the Data base
DBdata : customInterface2 = {
     city1 : 'string',
     city2 : 'string',
     city3 : 'string',
     etc....}
```

Html side :

```
<div *ngFor="let data of information">
    <div *ngIf="data.zone== 'europe'">
         <div *ngFor="let city of data.names">
              {{city.title}} : {{ DBdata.city.dbName }}
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it is more clear with the example. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your desired result, you can use the bracket notation (`[]`) to access dynamic properties based on the values from your `information` array. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
// Custom property
information: customInterface[] = [
  {
    zone: "europe",
    names: [
      { dbName: "city1", title: "Paris" },
      { dbName: "city2", title: "Madrid" },
      { dbName: "city3", title: "Berlin" },
      { dbName: "city4", title: "Rome" },
    ]
  },
  // Add more entries as needed
];

// Property storing data from the database
DBdata: customInterface2 = {
  city1: 'Data for City 1',
  city2: 'Data for City 2',
  city3: 'Data for City 3',
  // Add more entries as needed
};
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of information">
  <div *ngIf="data.zone === 'europe'">
    <div *ngFor="let city of data.names">
      {{ city.title }}: {{ DBdata[city.dbName] }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this code, the `DBdata` object uses the bracket notation to access the dynamic properties based on the `dbName` values from the `information` array. This allows you to interpolate the corresponding values dynamically.

Note that you need to ensure that the `DBdata` object has properties with names matching the `dbName` values defined in your `information` array for this approach to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work;

`DBData[city.dbName]`

This would make use the bracket syntax for accessing object properties - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp